# Prevent windows encrypted folder contents from being listed?

Tags: windows-10, encryption

I have encrypted folder by checking "Encrypt contents to secure data", then checked "Encrypt folder and everything within".

The problem is when another user logs in, he can see names of the files in encrypted folder.

Can it be prevented, so that other users cannot get inside this folder at all? Also, more important, is it possible to prevent folder listing when somebody has direct access to hard drive itself?

I know it can be done using tools like VeraCrypt, I wonder if it can be done using native Windows tools.

Btw, I am using Windows 10

Comment: On your local system you can setup NTFS permissions accordingly. If someone has physical access to your drive there isn't much you can do about it.

Comment: If you don't want the contents of a folder being listed by a specific user then the user's `Read` permission and/or the `List Folder/ read data` advanced permissions.  They will be unable to even access the folder if they don't have `Read` permissions to the folder.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, for Windows Server, there is Access-based enumeration, it displays only the files and folders that a user has permissions to access. For Windows Client, we can control user operation on file/folder via file and folder permissions. Manually change the “users” group, or, specific user account permission on the folder/file.

**File and Folder Permissions:**
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb727008.aspx

Comment: I wonder if it is going to protect from direct hard drive access, e.g. somebody just takes hard drive out and mounts it to another OS.